# Weak derivative for sobolev spaces in manifolds and vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

In these lecture notes [https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf) I read how one can define sobolev spaces between a riemannian manifold and a vector bundle over it. First I don't understand the definition that he makes of weak derivative. It goes like this

> Let $u\in L^1_{loc}(E)$ and $v\in L^1_{loc}(T^*M^{\otimes m}\otimes E)$. We say that $\nabla^m u=v$ weakly if $\int_{M}\langle v,\phi \rangle dV_g=\int_M \langle u, (\nabla ^m)^* \phi\rangle dV_g $ for any $u\in C_0^{\infty}(T^*M^{\otimes m}\otimes E)$.

Where is the $\phi $ coming from ? Shouldn't it be the one that is arbitrary ? Also what is the notation $(\nabla ^m)^*$ ?

Now I am trying to work out a concrete example and I am having some trouble checking what really is the weak derivative.

Suppose we have a manifold $M$, and $x:[0,1]\rightarrow T^*M$ be a smooth map. We can define the sobolev space $W^{1,1}([0,1], x^*(T^*M))$.  Now I am interested in seeing what is the weak derivative of $x$, will it be $\dot x$? I know that if we are working with sobolev spaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the weak derivative coincides with the usual derivative , if the latter exists, but I am not sure the same happens in this case? Will the weak derivative be $\dot x$?

Any  help is appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: $(\nabla ^m)^*$ is just the formal adjoint to $\nabla ^m$.

Comment: This is a typo. It should be “for any $\phi$,” not “for any $u$.”

Comment: The definition you wrote applies to sections of a bundle over $M$, while your example deals with a path in $M$. I don't see how the former applies to the latter. A more instructive example would be to look at a smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ (regardedas a section of $E=M\times\mathbb{R}$) and show that the derivative $\nabla^mf$ is a weak derivative of $f$.